# leonardo mouse readings

Tags: i2c, arduino-leonardo, mouse

hi there im using arduino uno + usb host shield and i have taken the readings from the usb mouse in this line of code : x =  mi->dX;
and the x output is the speed of the mouse x coordinates
and i wanna make it thru an analog  reading from 0 to 1023 i should do a constrain and a map
then i send the data thru i2c comm and recieve them with a slave code and display them but the mouse on the screen is moving always when i give the mouse a left move the mouse moves always to left and when i gave the mouse roght it moves to the right always without stopping the cursor as if im giving it a speed direction + or - .

this is the master code :

```
#include<Wire.h>   
#include <hidboot.h>
#include <usbhub.h>
#ifdef dobogusinclude
#include <spi4teensy3.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#endif
int x; // mouse x
int y; // mouse y
int y1;
int x1;
int l,r;
int x11,y11;
class MouseRptParser : public MouseReportParser
{
protected:
void OnMouseMove (MOUSEINFO *mi);
void OnLeftButtonUp (MOUSEINFO *mi);
void OnLeftButtonDown (MOUSEINFO *mi);
void OnRightButtonUp (MOUSEINFO *mi);
void OnRightButtonDown (MOUSEINFO *mi);
void OnMiddleButtonUp (MOUSEINFO *mi);
void OnMiddleButtonDown (MOUSEINFO *mi);
};
void MouseRptParser::OnMouseMove(MOUSEINFO *mi)
{
x =  mi->dX;
//x = constrain(x, 0, 1023);

Serial.println(x);

y =  mi->dY;
//y = constrain(y, 0, 1023);

Serial.println(y);

};
void MouseRptParser::OnLeftButtonUp (MOUSEINFO *mi)
{
Serial.println("L Butt Up");
l=0;
};
void MouseRptParser::OnLeftButtonDown (MOUSEINFO *mi)
{
Serial.println("L Butt Dn");
l=1;
};
void MouseRptParser::OnRightButtonUp (MOUSEINFO *mi)
{
Serial.println("R Butt Up");
r=0;
};
void MouseRptParser::OnRightButtonDown (MOUSEINFO *mi)
{
Serial.println("R Butt Dn");
r=1;
};
void MouseRptParser::OnMiddleButtonUp (MOUSEINFO *mi)
{
Serial.println("M Butt Up");
};
void MouseRptParser::OnMiddleButtonDown (MOUSEINFO *mi)
{
Serial.println("M Butt Dn");
x = 90;
y = 90;
};

USB Usb;
USBHub Hub(&Usb);
HIDBoot<USB_HID_PROTOCOL_MOUSE> HidMouse(&Usb);

uint32_t next_time;

MouseRptParser Prs;

void setup()
{
//Serial.begin(9600); 

Wire.begin();       //Begins I2C communication at pin (A4,A5)


Serial.begin(115200);
#if !defined(__MIPSEL__)
while (!Serial); // Wait for serial port to connect - used on Leonardo, Teensy and other boards with built-in USB CDC serial connection
#endif
Serial.println("Start");

if (Usb.Init() == -1)
Serial.println("OSC did not start.");

delay( 200 );

next_time = millis() + 5000;

HidMouse.SetReportParser(0, &Prs);
}

void loop()
{
Usb.Task();
Wire.beginTransmission(8);                         
Wire.write(x);
Wire.write(y);
//Wire.write(l);
//Wire.write(r);                                             
                                             
Wire.endTransmission();
delay(10);     

}
```

and the output is speed direction of x and y :

0
0
0
1
1
2
3
4
5
66
66
78
99
102
113
22
3
0
and this is the slave code :

```
#include<Wire.h>   
int x,y,l,r;
#include <Mouse.h>                                                                               // Analog output of vertical joystick pin

void setup() {
Serial.begin( 115200 ); // start serial for output
Wire.begin(8);
Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);
Mouse.begin(); //Init mouse emulation 
}

void receiveEvent( int bytes )
{

x = Wire.read();
y = Wire.read();
//l = Wire.read();
//r = Wire.read();
delay(10);     
}

void loop() {

Mouse.move(x, y, 0); // move mouse on y axis
delay(10);
}
```

anyone could help please i think the problem is i should ask the current position  and the next postion and if it was not zero move the mouse otherwise if it is 0 do not move

Comment: Well, you *are* constantly sending the X and Y coordinates over and over and over again in loop()...

Comment: so what to do ?

Comment: Don't keep sending them? Only send them when you receive them from the mouse?

Comment: you really need to learn how to format your code properly ... it is not a problem when the code is short,  but when the code is more complicated, correct indentation is very important when trying to find missed braces

Comment: could you please show me how ?

Comment: look at the example code that is included in the Arduino IDE